# Hibernate OneToMany JoinColmuns and Constant Value

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a generic relationship between Data and Parameter like this:

```
enum ParameterType { RISK, ASSET }

class Data {

   Long id;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name="data_id")
     @// Restrict DataParameter.type = 'RISK'
   })
   Set<DataParameter> risks;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name="data_id")
     @// Restrict DataParameter.type = 'ASSET'
   })
   Set<DataParameter> assets;
}

class DataParameter {

   Long id;

   ParameterType type;

   @ManyToOne
   Parameter parameter;
   @Temporal
   Date date;
   ...

}
```

How would manage to restrict this relationship using considering the ParameterType? I am using Hibernate 4.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can limit it by giving condition (SQL) in Hibernate specific [@Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotation. In this case following should work:

```
   //other annotations as they where 
   @Where(clause="type=0")
   Set<DataParameter> risks;
```

And then same with value 1 for assets.

Comment: What about the Cascade? Will Hibernate be able to cascade the relationship?

Comment: @Where affects only fetching of values from database. Cascades will work normally. Additionally input to these lists from application itself should be programmatically limited to preferred values of *type*